# Automatically setting up unit test projects in VS2008, need help

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I'm beginning to toy with the new ASP.NET MVC framework, and reading around in some tutorials I saw that in addition to creating the MVC project, theres an option to add a Unit Test project, using the Test framework (which I have) thats basically already set up for MVC testing.
Its supposed to pop up when you create a new MVC project, and look like this -

[http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/mvc/images/mvcCreateUnitTestProject.PNG http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/mvc/images/mvcCreateUnitTestProject.PNG](http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/mvc/images/mvcCreateUnitTestProject.PNG)

But it doesn't, and I'm forced to create the Unit Test project myself by adding it into the solution, which is time consuming and generally annoying to do considering the MVC project structure...
I've looked around the Test framework settings and found no way to make that window appear, or find any option to create an MVC test project.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you close the question or mark your answer;-)

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, reinstalling the MVC framework corrected the problem